# What is the available information about the files and folder inside the docker container?

Tags: docker

Using docker remote API **`HEAD /containers/(id)/archive?path=/root`**, we can get the following information:

```
{
    "name": "root",
    "size": 4096,
    "mode": 2147484096,
    "mtime": "2014-02-27T20:51:23Z",
    "linkTarget": ""
}
```

But the docker documentation does not provide any information about the various fields in the response.
I particular, I would like to know the what "`mode`" and "`linkTarget`" fields specifies.

Any pointer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes from [`container/archive.go#L62-L68`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/168b490062aed36bf95426d9d66dcf5703842016/container/archive.go#L62-L68)

```
return &types.ContainerPathStat{
        Name:       filepath.Base(absPath),
        Size:       lstat.Size(),
        Mode:       lstat.Mode(),
        Mtime:      lstat.ModTime(),
        LinkTarget: linkTarget,
    }, nil
```

Which means:

- `mode` is from [`FileInfo`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo).[`FileMode`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode)

> A `FileMode` represents a file's mode and permission bits.
>   The bits have the same definition on all systems, so that information about files can be moved from one system to another portably. Not all bits apply to all systems.

- `linkTarget` is `filepath.Rel(container.BaseFS, hostPath)`
  (relative path between the container base filesystem and the hostpath).